# ReClassify Vector Data Between Values using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, reclassify

I would like to be able to take all values between 1 and 10 and have a field define them as 1, and all values between 10 and 20 and set them to 2, how do I do that with vector data?

I read how to set all building to 20, and grass to 40, but I'm pretty sure that to do that for a range of values, like 1-10, I would have to manually enter each number, and decimal in that range. Am I wrong? and if not, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: There is a mistake in the Expression; it should read:
Expression:
Reclass(!WELLYIELD!) NOT Reclass(!WELLYIELD!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Job for the Field Calculator.

See this Python example at [Calculate Field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000)

```py
Parser:
Python

Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
  if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
    return 1
  elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
    return 2
  elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
    return 3
  elif (WellYield > 30):
    return 4
```

Comment: Are you aware that Python has an `int()` function built in?  Consider what the expression `1 + int((WellYield-1) / 10)` will do.

Comment: @whuber: I was aware of the int() function, but hadn't thought of using it  this way.

Comment: That's why I pointed it out :-).  Int() and its relatives, such as floor(), ceiling(), round(), and integer division, are the workhorses of reclassification because they are *step functions*: they attain a constant value over an interval and then jump to another value.  (Their graphs in Cartesian coordinates look like stairsteps in profile.)  Whenever you find yourself coding multiple `if` statements (in any language) to reclassify numerical values, think about using int() *et al.* to simplify the work (and speed the computation).