# Reclassifying a field in vector files in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, tools, reclassify

ArcGIS has a reclassify tool that works with Raster files only. 
Is it possible to have the same functionality for a vector file?

On the basis of one of the fields in a feature class, the tool should:

1. Add a new field in a new file or in the same feature class with the new re-classed values.
2. I know this can be done using a look up table (LUT) and then joining the two tables. But I want this tool to go inside a model so that the user can change the values again and again using the user interface.

Comment: Maybe this question is similar http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/reclassify-vector-data-between-values

Comment: Is this the [Reclassify tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclassify/00q90000007n000000/) that you are trying to emulate the functionality of?  Are you wanting the user to be able to add N values to the tool dialog?  If so, perhaps how to do that part of your tool should become the focus of the Question because the first part is just an Add Field.