# reclassify vector data from multiple source data fields (ArcGIS) (ModelBuilder)

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, vector, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and ModelBuilder. I am not familiar with Python.

My question is very similar to [ReClassify Vector Data Between Values using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/reclassify-vector-data-between-values) . However that question is about reclassification using the values from one other field.

I have experience of using this type of reclassification within the Calculate Value Tool.

However I wish to base a reclassification on the values from more than one source data field. For example from two fields - "Land" and "WellYield". ideally I'd like to be able to run classifications from 2 or 3 source fields.

I know the following code is wrong because i have not defined the "Land" field.

e.g.

parser:
Python

```
    Expression:
    Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!, !Land!)

    Code Block:
    def Reclass(WellYield, Land):
      if (WellYield == 'Make'and Land == 'Natural'):
        return 'Greenspace'
      elif (WellYield =='Multiple'  and Land == 'Natural'):
        return 'Not Greenspace'
```

Any help or tips on the correct code would be much appreciated.

I have just been testing some outputs by trial and error.

The above code seems to work now for classifying by different data fields. I will test further by three fields.

Any insights or advice would still be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to and an `else` statement in case there are instances where land is natural but wellyield isn't make or multiple.

Comment: Other than @Paul comment (+1) the code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

In Model Builder You can use Insert -> Iterators -> Feature selection where you select "group by" fields. It works like combine function for raster data. As output you have Value that you can use as a name of the output : outputlayer_%Value%.
It creates layers like : 
outputlayer_Make_Natural
outputlayer_Multiple_Natural
...