# Add classification value to attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, classification, python-parser, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to create a score for values in a table based off where the values fall within a classification range.

Have:

- Attribute table with income, range= $29,725 - $76,996
  [image]
- Layer Properties menu that breaks ranges into 3 equal intervals

Want: 
Add equal interval label (1, 2, or 3) values back into yet empty income score field (IncScore).[image]

Need to repeat for ~20 fields in the table and this will take a while to field calculate manually...

I am not Python savvy- but could follow a step-by-step solution if someone could explain as if I am a complete novice...

Comment: If you do not know Python just make three separate Select By Attributes and perform a different field calculation on each. For help with Python we need you to show what you have tried.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179280/how-to-give-polygons-a-classificaton-code-in-arcgis/179315#179315

Answer (score 3):

Not Python savvy either. But I think it will take more time to do Python scripting in this situation. All you need to do is to type in these in "Select by Attributes":

[image: 1st group]

Then you will get your first group selected. Use field calculator to make their score equal 1.

Do the same for the other 2 groups